# Android rtsp streaming with multiple video view

Tags: android

I split the full screen into two video view to stream two different URI on respective video view,but the video URI loads one URI in two video views.

Below both vv_left and vv_right streams the first uri(“xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:1234”)

```
private void generateUI(){
....
....
loadUri(vv_left,"xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:1234");
loadUri(vv_right,"xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:2345");
....
}

private void loadUri(VideoView vv,String url){
Uri uri= Uri.parse(url);
vv.setVideoURI(uri);
vv.requestFocus();
vv.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `MediaController` and request video `uri` separately for both `VideoViews`. that is:

```
VideoView videoView1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        VideoView videoView2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView2);

    try
            {
                MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);

                mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

                videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

                videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:1234));

                videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
                {               
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                    {   

                        videoView.start();

                        videoView.requestFocus();

                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Exception caught: "+e.getMessage());
            }
// do the same above try catch code for videoView2 and url2
```

Hope this will help you.